# Pass certain value safely to webapp for that session through url

Tags: c#, security, url, session-variables

I am building a web app in c# and I have the following question.

I am looking for a way to pass a value like an **"Id"** through my url to my webapp in a safe way for that session.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to pass through URL then you might need `querystring`. About safe way you need to elaborate further, what kind of safety? Also it will be good to show some code. Are you passing `Id` within same application?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Generally URLs are not the right place for secret data. For example those values often end up in log files, e.g. of a reverse proxy in front of your C# server. Why don't you `POST` them?

Comment: Well, I have no code yet because i don't know how to approach this problem. As for safety the idea is to have a qr code url value: www.urltomywebapp.be/value=1 (wich would make the QR code unique for this user and that way my web app knows about which user it is). As for safety I just want that the person who scans the code can't alter the url manually to say for example www.urltomywebapp.be/value=2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot stop a user from altering anything client-side.

If your URL was `www.example.com/ViewOrder.aspx?id=232` and you wanted to stop the user from viewing orders that were not theirs by changing the number, you would need to implement some security checks server that the current user has permission to access the order.

e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

    string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

    if (OrderService.GetOrder(id).User.Username == username)
    {
      Response.Write("id is " + id);
    }
    else
    {
      throw new SecurityException("User does not have permission to access another user's order.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I can now say: www.url.be/?id=1

And show it on the page_load:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{




    string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
    if (id != null)
    {
        Response.Write("id is ");
        Label1.Text = id;
    } 
}
```

Now this is not safe at all, so is there a way to pass the ?id=1 on a way that the user can't alter the id.

Comment: Don't pass the id as int, rather use a GUID, their not that easy to guess